# Need to append excel file in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have a task wherein I have to get only today's data in excel file, like if i run the package tomorrow it will only shows tomorrow's data.

What I am doing is,

1. on control flow task, I am having 2 execute SQL task and 1 Data flow task
2. On first execute sql task I am selecting the connection type as Excel and statement as

   ```
   DROP TABLE `Excel Destination`
   ```
3. On second execute sql task I am selecting the connection type as Excel and statement as

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `Excel Destination` (
   `Id` Long
   )
   ```
4. on data flow task I am taking source as OLE DB and destination as Excel.

But everytime I run the package it is still appending the excel and not over-riding. Can anyone help me and let me know what is the problem in the above package

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right way, you can follow this article for a detailed answer

- https://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/ssis-dynamically-generate-excel-tablesheet/

**Just do the following editing**

- in the create statment try using `DOUBLE` instead of `LONG`
- in the excel destination don't select the sheet name from the combobox but choose to add  new  table with the create sql command you provided. *(take a look at the link above)*